# Can't access a serial port in c

Tags: c, windows, serial-port

Trying to get to grips with C and accessing serial ports, fairly new to this, so used this code I found in a tutorial:

```
   #include<windows.h>
   #include<stdio.h>
   int main()
   {
    HANDLE hComm;

    hComm = CreateFile("COM3",                //port name
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, //Read/Write
        0,                            // No Sharing
        NULL,                         // No Security
        OPEN_EXISTING,// Open existing port only
        0,            // Non Overlapped I/O
        NULL);        // Null for Comm Devices

    if (hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("Error in opening serial port");
    }
    else {
        printf("Opening serial port successful");
        printf("It works!!!");
    }


    CloseHandle(hComm);//Closing the Serial Port

    return 0;
}
```

However hComm keeps returning `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. I checked that my serial port was COM3, and tried with `\\\\.\\COM3` and `COM:3`, but both made no difference. My drivers are updated, and my serial port is working. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You tagged C++, but your question and title are about C.  They are different languages.  I suggest you remove the C++ tag.

Comment: Have you tried "COM3:"?

Comment: In working code of mine I use TCHAR *pcCommPort = TEXT("COM3"); What does your GetLastError() say?

Comment: What does `GetLastError()` return?  That should give you more information about why it is failing.